# Animate on div not working after I call it after the first animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create some tiles which randomly move upward and downward inside a div which is inside a div with the property "overflow:hidden"

```
setInterval(function(){
      for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if($(".contacttiles").eq(i).attr('noanimate')!='true'){
          $(".contacttiles").eq(i).delay(Math.floor((Math.random()*3000)+1)).animate({top:-120},1000,function(){
          $(".contacttiles").eq(i).delay(3000).animate({top:0},1000);
          })
        }
      }
    })
  },7000)
```

here the 'contacttiles' are the class in which the divs which should move are included
the animation works fine for the first part. The tiles go up. But the second part is not working. I tried an alert('hi') and animation of another element in the second part both of them worked. However the second part of the above code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `i` will be `undefined` when the function you passed to `delay` runs.

Try scoping the content of your for loop:

```
setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            if ($(".contacttiles").eq(i).attr('noanimate') != 'true') {
                $(".contacttiles").eq(i).delay(Math.floor((Math.random() * 3000) + 1)).animate({
                    top: -120
                }, 1000, function () {
                    $(".contacttiles").eq(i).delay(3000).animate({
                        top: 0
                    }, 1000);
                })
            }
        })(i)
    }
}, 7000)
```